# virtual machine on azure virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, azure, windows-server-2016

Can I run another virtual machines inside Microsoft azure virtual machine? 16 cores, 56gb of ram, but I got errors about virtualization:

Hyper-V install feature:

"Hyper-V cannot be installed: The processor does not have the required virtualization capabilities."

VirtualBox error message:
"VT-x is not available"

can I somehow resolve this? Im running windows server 2016 r2

Comment: No, you can't nest VT-X.

Comment: A little unsupported workaround https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gbanin/2013/06/25/how-to-install-hyper-v-on-a-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant do that yet, even with Server 2016 nested virtualization is not available. Keep an eye on the Azure road map, it might be a feature they introduce on the future:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/roadmap/